# javax.microedition.io where can i find the jar?

Tags: java, java-me

I know this is very trivial , but i have installed J2Me .I just want to use **javax.microedition.io.HTTP** apis , where can find a jar which i can import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

findjar is your friend.

http://findjar.com/index.x?query=javax.microedition.io.HTTP

Comment: Thanks kal :) findjar is awesome

Comment: @KC203 -- yes. I find that I go to it about 3-4 times a month because of some obscure missing class especially in legacy applications.

Comment: '2018, happily findjar still works - but if you're restricted to maven-central then the **fc** parameter can be used, e.g. https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:%22javax.microedition.io.HTTPConnection%22